# Snapshot QueryParams can't get attributes Ionic/angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to access my object name, not the complete data object from the snapshot `queryParams`.

My code looks like this

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class ItemPage implements OnInit {

  id:any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    const data = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
  }
}
```

My console output looks like this:

```json
{"data":"{\"name\":\"abs\",\"id\":1}"}
```

I am not able to access the complete data via `JSON.stringify(data?.data)`

Also I can not write:

```js
const currentObject = JSON.stringify(data.data); 
console.log(currentObject.name);
```

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` will obviously create a `string` from your JSON, so you won't be able to get an attribute from this object after. Don't use `JSON.stringify` and you will be able to access your data.

Comment: Just write `console.log(data.data?.name)` and you should see the value `abs` in console.